# Ruby Watir: Avoid the "Im not a robot" check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, google-chrome, watir

I'm using watir to load a page the following way:

```
Watir.default_timeout = Rails.cache.read(:wati_timeout) || 5
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.headless!
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: options
browser.goto(url)
```

This loads a captcha page with "Please wait... we are checking your browser. and contains a "I am human" checkbox.

I there a way to prevent the website from triggering the captcha?

Answer (score 0):

The Captchas were invented in order to prevent bots and crawlers(like selenium). They are made to be done manually.
You might work around this by automating everything except the Captcha.
You might also want to pause the selenium program if it detects a captcha, so you can solve it and then continue manually.

"I there a way to prevent the website from triggering the captcha?"
You can make it more unlikely to appear by not using a VPN and allowing selenium to use and keep cookies(don't know if this is on by default).